# Encountering LaTeX error when attempting to knit pdf/word - execution halted

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

I am relatively new to R and would like to knit PDF for a linear regression assignment using Rmarkdown. RStudio Version 2022.12.0+353 (2022.12.0+353)

I keep encountering this error when attempting to Knit to PDF:

```
output file: Homework1.knit.md

! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ≥ (U+2265)
not set up for use with LaTeX.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Homework1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Homework1.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I've tried updating my R and LaTeX packages, as well as the steps mentioned with the link provided in the error message:

```
> update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
> tinytex::tlmgr_update()
```

Unsure how to go about solving this issue.

Comment: The easiest way to avoid such errors is to compile with an unicode aware engine like xelatex or lualatex

Comment: Thank you! I believe the issue was using the greater or equal to sign "≥" in the rmarkdown file. Removing it allowed me to produce the pdf. However, I am unsure how to incorporate this into the file. How would I compile with xelatex/lualatex/etc.?

Comment: How to switch to an unicode aware engine will depend on your setup. You should add a [mre] to your question which shows your header and a test document to reproduce the problem.